# Non-functional laptop screen, suddenly starts working after CheckDisk (but than dies again)

Tags: display, hardware-failure, check-disk

I got a very mysterious problem.

I got an *HP Pavilion DV7-2270US 17.3'*, that serves me for the last *3 years* (bought at 09/11).

**About 1 year ago the laptop screen just stopped working** (without any given reason. I did not hurt it or something like). I connected an external monitor, through the vga port, and learned to live with it.

One day I had to perform a ***CheckDisk***, and to my astonishment, **the screen returned working**. I was in shock. Everything seems like as it was before it stopped working. No issues. Nothing.

Seems like the CheckDisk fix some bad sector, and thats probably resolved it.

---

Now... why i'm writing all of this to you?

**Today I had to take my laptop outside of the house** (I use it as a desktop really. I usually never take it outside of my house), and when I got to my friends house, **the screen stopped working again**!

I have not bit, drop, hurt or shake it. Really- it was just a matter of few apartments away. I carried it in a safety bag and really took care about.

---

**What are your ideas regarding it?**

What can I do? I have tried running checkdisk again, reinstalled monitor drivers, nothing.

I must mention that the monitor is working, it just output very week & low light. You need to place your eye very close to the screen in order to manage to see the image.

I truly hope someone here might help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that badblock doesn't fix that problem first time. It's more likely you have a cable contact to lcd inverter not connected properly or your inverter is bad. You may try to apply decent pressure along display sides. But this definitely looks like HW problem otherwise your monitor would work at Startup screen.

Comment: **Thank you man!** This laptop monitor been installed by me long time ago after I broke the original one (by hitting the ground). I have opened already and tried seing whats the deal, and couldn't make it, but now with your directions I'll go straight to the inverter. before I just checked the connections. Thank you again!

Comment: hey @week, I opened the screen again, and theres nothing loose that seems like I can fix. Take a look. I uploaded a photo. http://s5.postimage.org/x4c1wq9rb/photo.jpg. What do you say?

Comment: Here is the pc open totally - http://s5.postimage.org/xiddwbtuv/photo.jpg. Thank you for your help! I'll appreciate it.

Comment: That seams I was wrong about inverter, you have a LED monitor. Sorry about that, I should check. That main lcd cable under sticker is connected properly?

Comment: Yap... It's really seems like everything is well connected to each other...

Comment: Have you checked connection on motherboard?

Comment: have not. I guess thats my next step, isn't it? Never opened my laptop, but I think i'll be just fine :) Thank you for your instructions. Please, after we will discover the problem, answer my question, and I'll approve it. I wana show you my regards.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same thing happen to me with my HP laptop, date of manufacture 2018. The answer you have above is probably correct, but also I was told anonymousely by a HP tech, that HP is notorious for using cheap solder. From what I get, HP and others do not put a large enough fan to keep things cool and in combination with inferior solder, shorts or cold solders happen.